# Blocks of records in sql server ce

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have an application that works with SQL Compact.

I have this query:

```
"SELECT * FROM [AlarmsHistory] WHERE (DATEPART (year, StartTime) = {0}) AND (DATEPART (month, StartTime) = {1}) AND (DATEPART (day, StartTime) = {2})";
```

but since I could even get up to 5000 records would get at most 200 to be displayed in a table.
Clicking on a button on the application the user needs to see another block of 200 records.
How do I write a query to get the various blocks of records?

Answer (score 0):

Using version 2012 you could use OFFSET ... FETCH block with the ORDER BY clause.

```
SELECT * FROM [AlarmsHistory] 
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ... OFFSET 200 ROWS FETCH NEXT 200 ROWS ONLY
```